# How to get HDFS and YARN version programmatically?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm writing a spark program that download different jars from maven based on the environment it runs on, each for a different version of Hadoop distribution (e.g. CDH, HDP, MapR).

This is necessary because some low-level APIs of HDFS and YARN are not shared between these distributions. However, I cannot find any public API of HDFS and YARN that tells their version.

Is it possible to do it only in Java? Or I have to run an external shell to know it?

Answer (score 3):

In Java org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion() should work.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/VersionInfo.html

For the CLIs, you can use:

```
$ hadoop version
$ hdfs version
$ yarn version
```